# ajax in wordpress and wp_query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

In my funcitons.php file i have function that response to ajax call and return posts:

functions.php:

```
function returnPosts(){
if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
        }
    } else { 
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
    }
exit();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_returnPosts', 'returnPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_returnPosts', 'returnPosts');
```

Javascript (in index.php):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>",
    data: {"action": "returnPosts"},
    success:function(results){
        // Work with results
    }
});
```

But when i call this function via JS i always get content from content-none.php file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming the AJAX call will know what post is being displayed on the page already, since you're checking have_posts() without creating your own WP_Query. But an AJAX call comes in as a separate HTTP request, and the only things it knows about the previous page are the things you tell it.

In additon to passing your "action" name in the AJAX call, try passing the current post's ID. I'm not in front of a real computer to test this, but this should work assuming you're inside a Loop when that jQuery code is output:

```
data: {"action": "returnPosts", "p": "<?php the_ID(); ?>"},
```

Answer (score -2):

Quick fix is to:

`include("../../../wp-load.php");` <-- guessing at the location of the wordpress file.

at the top of the php file.

Comment: No it´s not work. I thing the problem is that wp_query variable is not defined.